# Can eclipse m2e share the maven cache between workspaces?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Each one of my eclipse workspaces contains a 2.5GB cache inside the org.eclipse.m2e.core plugin directory. Is there any way this can be shared across workspaces?

(I have about 30 workspaces, out of necessity)

Comment: For me the `org.eclipse.m2e.core` is around `800 KB`. Could you please share the `settings.xml`?

Comment: My local repo settings?

Comment: Yes, especially the tag `<localRepository>`.

Comment: Don't think I have that tag. Maven is using the default location ~/.m2/repository/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the https://maven.apache.org/settings.html, I provide the dedicated directory for `<localRepository>` as the following example

The `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" 
          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <localRepository>path/to/repository</localRepository>
<settings>
```

Note: I use the Eclipse for Windows the menu may be different from your.

The `Eclipse m2e` configuration is as the following: -

1. Create new clean workspace.
2. Goto `Windows` --> `Preferences`, the system will display the `Preferences` dialog.
3. At the `Preferences` dialog, choose `Maven` --> `User Settings`.
4. At the right panel

   - Set the `User Settings` text box to `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`.
   - Press the button named `Update Settings`
   - The text box named `Local Repository (From merged user and global settings)` should display the path `path/to/repository` as same as the value from tag `<localRepository>`.
5. Create new maven project
6. Monitor the `org.eclipse.m2e.core`, the size should be reduced.

Comment: This just changes the path of the local repository. It doesn't affect the eclipse maven cache. The repository cache is still duplicated within each workspace.